# Can't destructure from event.body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, prop, destructure

I am having an issue where I can't destructure from event.body.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const { items } = event.body;
    const allItems = await getProducts();

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: 'I have charged your card!',
    };
};
```

If I look at event.body, I get `{"items":[{"id":12,"quantity":4}]}` but when I try and get items from event.body, it always comes back as undefined.

So I believe the issue is in my getProducts function.

```
const getProducts = async () => {
    const categories = [];
    const items = [];
    const r = await fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => FireStoreParser(json))
        .then(json => {
            const documents = json['documents'];
            Object.keys(documents).forEach(function(key) {
                categories.push(documents[key]);

                Object.keys(categories[key]['fields']).forEach(function(key2) {
                    items.push(categories[key]['fields']['items']);
                });
            });
        });

    return items;
```

I need to access each items id. This is what getProducts returns

```
[
  [
    {
      price: 220,
      imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/0s3pdnc/adidas-nmd.png',
      name: 'Adidas NMD',
      id: 10
    },
    {
      name: 'Adidas Yeezy',
      price: 280,
      id: 11,
      imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/dJbG1cT/yeezy.png'
    },
    {
      imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/bPmVXyP/black-converse.png',
      price: 110,
      id: 12,
      name: 'Black Converse'
    },
    {
      imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/1RcFPk0/white-nike-high-tops.png',
      id: 13,
      price: 160,
      name: 'Nike White AirForce'
    }
]
]
```

Comment: is `event.body` a string or an object?

Comment: ^^ because `undefined` is what you get if you do `const { items } = "any string";`

Comment: Apparently it is a string. How would I pull the id from it then?

Comment: `const { items } = JSON.parse(jsonString);`

Comment: `const { items } = JSON.parse(jsonString);`

This works but sometimes it would contain multiple items so how would I iterate over it and get each item

`const cartWithProducts = items.map(({ id, quantity }) => {
  const item = allItems.find(p => p.id === id);
 });`

Item is always undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In my getProducts I need to return items[0] instead of just items.

Then in I just need to do this and I can get the correct item:

```
const cartWithProducts = items.map(({ id, quantity }) => {
        const item = allItems.find(p => p.id === id);
            console.log(item)
    });
```